# Can I use the same workspace for eclipse-java and eclipse-cpp?

Tags: eclipse

I downloaded eclipse-jee-juno-SR1-win32-x86_64 and created the workspace folder in mu user directory. Seems to work fine.

Then I downloaded eclipse-cpp-juno-SR2-win32-x86_64, but I cannot find an acceptable folder for the workspace.

How can I keep eclipse for java and for c++ in the same user directory?

Comment: You can, but this is not recommended.

Comment: Do not share completely unrelated projects in one workspace. That is the best way to performance issues and other unwanted nasty things.